# Does C have variant data types?

Tags: c

How to fix the c compiler error of below program?

```
struct a{
      int a;
};
struct b{
    int b;
};
int main(){

int toggle =1;
int y = (toggle==1) && (struct a x);
y =     (toggle==0) && (struct b x);

if(toggle==1){
    x.a = 10;
    printf("%d ",x.a);
}else {
    x.b = 20;
    printf("%d ",x.b);
}
printf("hi");
return 0;
}
```

When i compile this program am getting error "expected ')' before 'x'"

I need create static objects. Is there other way to achieve this?

Comment: What is `x`???? In fact what does `int y = (toggle ==1)&& (struct a x);
y =    (toggle==0)&&(struct b x);
x t;` mean ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't have declarations as part of an expression. You need to figure out another way of handling conditional compilation/declarations (perhaps using the preprocessor?).

---

One possible way may be to have a common base structure, with the "toggle" as a flag in it, and use pointer to this base-structure type-casted to the correct structure. A soft of "inhearitance" in C, so to say. Something like

```
enum Type
{
    TYPE_A,
    TYPE_B
};

struct Base
{
    int type;  /* One of the Type enumerations */
};

struct A
{
    struct Base base;
    int field_unique_to_a;
};

struct B
{
    struct Base base;
    double field_unique_to_b;
};

int main(void)
{
    int toggle = 1;
    struct Base *base_ptr;

    if (toggle == 1)
    {
        base_ptr = calloc(1, sizeof(A));  /* Use calloc to initialize the data */
        base_ptr->type = TYPE_A;
    }
    else
    {
        base_ptr = calloc(1, sizeof(B));  /* Use calloc to initialize the data */
        base_ptr->type = TYPE_B;
    }

    /* Now `base_ptr` points either to a `A` or a `B` structure */

    if (base_ptr->type == TYPE_A)
    {
        ((struct A *) base_ptr)->field_unique_to_a = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        ((struct B *) base_ptr)->field_unique_to_b = 12.34;
    }

    /* ... */
}
```